# How to create stdObject with one array in it?

Tags: php, stdclass

I get a value from a database, and if I dump it, I have:

```
myvar=stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'id' => '320646',
   'nameNormalized' => '27817759',
   'name' => 'Thename'
))
```

How could it be possible to create this same variable by hand? When I do this:

```
$myvar= new \stdClass(array(
   'id' => '320646',
   'nameNormalized' => '27817759',
   'name' => 'Thename',
));
var_export($myvar);
```

I get:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
))
```

Then how to do?

Comment: `stdClass` doesn't take a param. And there isn't an "array in it". You confuse the constructor with the `__set_state` method. What you're looking for is a typecast: `(object) array(...)`.

Comment: @mario did beat me to it :D http://codepad.viper-7.com/6MOGYS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
$myvar= (object)(array(
   'id' => '320646',
   'nameNormalized' => '27817759',
   'name' => 'Thename',
));
```

Comment: Hey, check this out http://blog.thoughtlabs.com/blog/2008/02/02/phps-mystical-__set_state-method